# Why can't Tyranus/Dooku sense Kenobi in Geonosis?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, attack-of-the-clones, obi-wan-kenobi, darth-tyranus

At this scene, Obi-Wan  overhears the Separatists 'plans. But one of the Separatist leaders is a Sith Lord, Count Dooku.

In *A New Hope*, when the crew of the Millennium Falcon boarded the  Death Star I, Darth Vader could sense that Obi-Wan was on the ship, and informed Tarkin that Obi-Wan was on the battle station.  **Now why couldn't Tyranus sense Kenobi on Geonosis, unlike Vader who sensed Kenobi on the Death Star I?** Dooku is force-sensitive because he was a rogue Jedi and a Sith Lord.

Comment: I'm not sure about Dooku specifically, but each Jedi has things they're better/worse at. Some Jedi are specifically better with the Living Force than others, which would help do things like detecting people spying on you.

Comment: @phantom42 except that Vader wasn't in tune with the Living Force.

Comment: You know these are the prequels, right? No offense meant, but the prequels are not the best of the Star Wars series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question if you don't mind.I saw a [*Youtube Comment by PolillaBenG*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4MdUrh7iZMU) that the comment is **"What made Obi-Wan think he could still sneak around after seeing Count Dooku? I thought Jedi and Sith could sense each other's presences, so he should've at least suspected Dooku knew he was there."** I saw majority of the replies of this comment that  Dooku sensed Obi Wan in Geonosis which I started to believe that it make sense. If you're going to ask me why?Dooku knew that Obi Wan was spying him. But he did that on purpose, by luring him into a trap. As you can see in the film, that he was captured so that Dooku would plant a seed to the Republic in order the Clone Wars would have begun as Sidious and Tyranus planned.

Answer (score 9):

Anakin was Obi-Wan's padawan for many years. As Vader, he was still very familiar with Obi-Wan's Force presence, even after not being around him for decades:

> I sense something... a presence I haven't felt since...

Dooku wasn't familiar with Obi-Wan's Force presence, so wouldn't have known what he felt like. That, and Obi-Wan was good at stealth and hiding his Force presence from other Force-sensitives. He just couldn't hide from his former padawan when in close proximity.

Comment: So kenobi is using force stealth? In other words

Comment: Also, there is a possibility Obi-Wan wanted to confront Darth Vader on Death Star, for various reasons.

Comment: What about kenobi and tyranus

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar what about them? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Did obi wan use force stealth when he overhears the separatists?

Comment: @TheWitchKingofAngmar I would expect so, since he was trying to learn their plans and didn't want to be caught, unlike on the Death Star.

Answer (score 0):

Anakin and Obi-wan are connected by the force. This was exploited by Palpatine and Count Dooku to try and turn Yoda to the dark side. The reason that Count Dooku doesn't sense Obi-wan is that he doesn't know him. Think of it like seeing someone's face, but instead of actually seeing their face you can only see the back of their head since you know what they look like you can easily deduce whos face that is. I believe it's like that. But like the force. Also, in Attack of the Clones Count Dooku actually senses Yoda entering and recognizes Yoda's force signature.